# How to reset $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST';

Tags: php

I have a form which is submitted via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST';` and then advances to the next page.  On the next page I want to give the users the choice to go back and edit the form data.  When I try to go back to the form page, the browser posts the "confirm form submisson" message.

This seems to only happen on Google Chrome, on Safari it works fine.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it does this?  Do I have to reset the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable when i go back a page?

Comment: Because to go back is to go back to a page created from a POST request. What else did you expect to happen?

Comment: Isn't this commonly solved/made with [Post/Redirect/Get (PRG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)? - Also please create a screenshot of that message, from the text alone it might not be that clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

You should redirect the user to an edit page, not the previous page in their browser. You could temporarily store the information in an session and load that information in on the edit page.

Answer (score 1):

You can better add the values in the database. An when someone goes back reload the values that are stored in the database. This is cleaner way to do the same as you want. In firefox you will get this message to and i guess in IE also.